# Weird behavior running Jade Platform on Eclipse OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, agents-jade

I was developing a JADE multi-agent platform using Eclipse under Windows 7 and it works great. Now I'm trying to move the code to a macbook pro with OS X Mavericks installed and I'm experiencing a very weird problem. I've installed java 1.6.0_65 and Eclipse Kepler and they seem to work fine (I've tried with other developments) When I try to run my JADE platform the rma agent ant its gui and my own agents and guis are created properly but, the weird thing is that I can interact with them, they seem to be freezed, or in background, or something like that. Even the top buttons: close, minimize, maximize, are like disabled. The only interaction I can make with all the windows/guis is to move them across the screen but... that's not what I want :) I copy here my running arguments on eclipse, the same I was using on Windows:

*gui -name TrhiosSimulationTool jade.Boot;Databaser:com.tst.database.DatabaseAgent;Evaluator:com.tst.evaluation.ObEvaluationAgent;Hierarcher:com.tst.hierarchy.HierarchyAgent;Reputer:com.tst.reputation.ReputationAgent;Simulator:com.tst.simulation.SimulationAgent;Socializer:com.tst.social.SocialAgent;Trainer:com.tst.reputation.training.TrainingHierarchyAgent*

I've tried to run JADE from the command line and showing the rma gui and it works so it seems it is not a problem with JADE but with how I run it from Eclipse. I tried to run my agents from command line but I'm not able to do it, I suppose I'm doing things wrong and have problems with the external libraries I use in some of the guis and agents.

I would appreciate any suggestion or idea you can provide to me because I'm a bit desperate :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've solved it!! I've just need to uncheck the "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT" checkbox on Arguments tab of Run Configurations.

Comment: I don't know how to close the question, sorry, I'm a bit new :(